# Late night public transit from Tel Aviv airport?

Tags: public-transport, airports, airport-transfer, israel, tlv

Is there any public transit from Ben Gurion airport to central Tel Aviv departing late enough that I'd be able to catch it after arriving (on an international flight) at 11:20 pm?

It seems the trains and Egged buses don't run late enough (the last train is at 11:35), but I don't know if I might have overlooked other public transit from the airport.

Comment: I know the answer for Friday night: none whatsoever. Not sure about other days.

Comment: On what day are you ariving?

Comment: Likely a non-Friday weekday in mid-November.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you will need to wait an hour or a bit more (it'll take time to get your luggage etc). This is what https://www.bus.co.il has on the matter and I seriously doubt there's anything in Israel that website misses:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer about the trains and the strange behaviour of the trains website.

The [Israeli Rail website](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) regards the trains that leave after midnight as train on the next day, and will not go to them when pressing on the "later" button when looking at train times, for example, the times for trains tonight (Nov, 8<sup>th</sup>, 2016) are:

[image: Evening trains on the Israeli Rail website]

In order to see the trains after midnight, you must make a new search for early the next day:

[image: Post-midnight trains on the Israeli Rail website]

So you can see that there is a train leaving at 23:35 and at 00:50. On normal weekdays, trains from Ben Gurion Airport to Tel Aviv are available all night, and those trains continue north to Nahariya but stop only on the fallowing stations:

- Tel Aviv-Savidor Center
- Hertsliya
- Netanya
- Hadera-West
- Binyamina
- Haifa-Hof HaKarmel (Razi`el)
- Haifa Center-HaShmona
- Kiryat Motzkin
- Ako
- Nahariya

On Fridays, trains stop in the afternoon, on this Friday the last train will leave at 14:55, the times change during the summer and winter.

On Saturday nights the train work with a slightly different time schedule, for example this coming Saturday trains leave at 23:25 and 00:50.

Holidays are like Saturdays, and the day before the holiday is like a Friday.

Comment: > So you can see that there is a train leaving at 23:56 and at 01:06. - Nope, those are arrival times, check again. It leaves at 23:35 as the OP asked. The other train leaves at 0:50 as my answer have showed.

Comment: At night the trains don't stop in all the stations in Tel Aviv.

Comment: @chx, thank I didn't notice it, changed the times. This answer comes more as a general answer to explain this strange behaviour of the rail site, less to actually answer the question of when does the train leave.

Comment: @SelaYair, added this info